# What's ```__new__``` by default in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, default-constructor, class-constructors

I believe I have some sort of understanding of what `__new__` is supposed to do (create an instance, of a class, but not initialize it, that is the job of `__init__`). I'd like to understand, however, what Python 3 implements as a `__new__` method by default.

I also find it somewhat confusing that `cls` is an argument for `__new__`, but `__new__` is a staticmethod and not a classmethod (I got this from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)). How does it know that it is being passed a type as its first argument?

Comment: 1. `object.__new__` is the default, what is to understand about it? 2. By checking `isinstance(cls, type)` or the equivalent in the language of the implementation.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ed70a344b5fbddea85726ebc1964ee0cfdef9c40/Objects/object.c#L276

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I never went into the CPython implementation, can you explain what is going on in there? it looks like something analogous to ```self.__init__()``` is returned?

Comment: @Goyo What do you mean? If ```object.__new__``` is the default, what does it do? Where can I find this info? Also, what about cls as an argument? Is ```__new__``` a classmethod?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can this be recreated in pure python or is this not possible?

Comment: @Ignacio possibly using ctypes, but why would you want to?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not interested in doing this, I just want to understand what is happening under the hood when I don't override ```__new__``` (preferably without going into CPython).

Comment: The actual object is created, i.e. some memory is allocated on the private heap. A reference to that memory is returned

Comment: It creates a new instance and returns a reference to it, but you already know that. The details are implementation-dependant but you are not interested in implementation details. So what is what you want to know?

Comment: `__new__` is a static method, that is already in your question too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First part: what does `__new__` do by default? Because the creation of an object from scratch is a fundamental, implementation-specific operation, the definition of `object.__new__` is necessarily (like the rest of the definition of `object`) part of the implementation itself. That means you need to look in the source code of CPython, PyPy, Cython, etc. to see exactly how object creation is managed in any particular implementation of Python. Typically, it's all low-level bookkeeping that can't be accessed directly from Python itself.

Second part: how does `__new__` know that it gets a class argument? Because it *assumes* its first argument is a class, and the caller had better provide a class if they expect `__new__` to work correctly! That said, nobody really ever calls `__new__` expclitly, except via `super` in an override of `__new__`, and then, you have to make sure to pass `cls` explicitly yourself:

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    rv = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)  # Not super().__new__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The rest of the time, you create an instance of a class `Foo` not by calling `Foo.__new__(Foo, ...)` directly, but just by calling the type itself: `Foo(...)`. *This* is managed because the `__call__` method of `Foo`'s metaclass takes care of calling `__new__` for your. For example, you can imagine that `type.__call__` is defined roughly as

```
# A regular instance method of type; we use cls instead of self to
# emphasize that an instance of a metaclass is a class
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    rv = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)  # Because __new__ is static!
    if isinstance(rv, cls):
        rv.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return rv
```

Note that `__init__` is only invoked if `__new__` actually returns an instance of the class calling `__new__` in the first place.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see now that this is what I was looking for. Your rough idea of how `__call__` works made things click for me. I think in this context I can understand much better what `__new__` does.

Comment: No, because `Foo(1,2,3)` is implemented by `type.__call__(Foo, 1, 2, 3)`. We really want to call `Foo.__new__`, not the `__new__` method of one of `type`'s ancestors.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding the default implementation of `__new__()` is something like this

```
class Default(object):
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    print("In new")
    return super().__new__(cls,*args, **kwargs)

def __init__(self):
    print("In init default")

default = Default()
print(type(default))
```

Output

```
In new
In init default
<class '__main__.Default'>
```

Based on the documentation
[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**new**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

> Typical implementations create a new instance of the class by invoking the superclass’s `__new__()` method using super().**new**(cls[, ...]) with appropriate arguments and then modifying the newly-created instance as necessary before returning it.

The `super().__new__()` call will create the instance and `__init__()` will initialize.

Below code shows an incorrect overriding of `__new__()`

```
class InccorectOverride(object):

def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

def __init__(self):
    print("In init InccorectOverride")

a = InccorectOverride()
print(type(a))
```

Output

```
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Since `__new__()` does not return the instance, the output has a value of NoneType

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Your question was

> If we do not override it, then what does `__new__` do in Python?

---

Suppose that we have a very simple class named `Point`. We instantiate the `Point` class as follows:

```python
# construct and initialize paula the point
paula = Point(10.2, 7.4)
```

In order to help explain what `__new__` does, I will write a classmethod named `make_point` which has almost the same behavior as calls to the class constructor, such as `paula = = Point(10.2, 7.4)`.

```python
class Point():
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("__new__(" + ", ".join(str(x) for x in [cls, *args]) + ")")
        obj = super().__new__(cls)
        return obj

    def __init__(self, y:float, y:float):
        args = (y, y)
        print("__init__(" + ", ".join(str(x) for x in [self, *args]) + ")")
        self._y = y
        self._y = y

    @classmethod
    def make_point(cls, *args):
        new_instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
        if isinstance(new_instance, cls):
            cls.__init__(new_instance, *args)
        return new_instance
```

Now we can instantiate the `Point` class as follows:

```python
peter = Point.make_point(59.87, 5.91)
```