# what does __new__ do in python class

Tags: python, class, oop, constructor

in the class concept of python, it states that __init __ initializes the class, which I understood as setting defaults to the class.
However, I bumped into a new concept called __new __, which states that it is used to control the creation of the class.
I have seen several explanations saying that __new __ also returns an instance, but I am also confused about what that is returning and to where.

Can someone clarify these points, please?

Comment: @metatoaster This might actually be a very good start for a canonical answer to the direct question of what is `__new__`. All other questions are a little indirect.

Comment: @Bharel if we are asking "what is `__new__`", [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421318/whats-new-by-default-in-python-3) should be the canonical.